# Hölder inequality conditions for $L_p$ spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

The [Hölder inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) is the statement that if $f,g$ are *measurable* functions then

$$ \|fg \|_1 \le \|f\|_p \|g\|_q$$

if $p,q$ are such that ${1\over p}+ {1 \over q} =1$.

But it's not clear to me why, if both $\|f\|_p$ and $ \|g\|_q$ are finite, this implies that $\|fg\|_1$ is, too.

> Is there an assumption missing in the statement on Wikipedia? (Like e.g. $f \in L_1 \cap L_p$.) Is there really no example of $f,g$ measurable such that $\|f\|_p$ and $ \|g\|_q$
>   are finite but $\|fg\|_1 = \infty$?

I know that *if the measure space $X$ is finite* then there is an $L_p$ space inclusion $L_q \subseteq L_p$ if $p < q$. But finiteness is not in the assumptions of the Hölder inequality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is part of the point of Hölder's inequality. It shows that if $f\in L^p$, $g\in L^q$ and $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$ then $fg\in L^1$. To see "why" this holds, I suggest you examine a proof of Hölder's inequality. I can provide one if you do not have one.

EDIT: The proof relies on Young's inequality: if $x,y\ge0$ then $xy\le\frac{x^p}p+\frac{y^q}q$. This inequality is obvious if $x$ or $y$ are zero, so assume $x,y>0$. For any $t\in[0,1]$, we have
$$\log(tx+(1-t)y)\ge t\log(x)+(1-t)\log(y)$$
which can be seen by observing the graph of $\log$. Setting $t=\frac1p$, we get
$$\log\left(\frac{x^p}p+\frac{y^q}q\right)\ge \frac1p\log(x^p)+\frac1q\log(y^q)=\log(xy)$$
from which Young's inequality follows.

Now we prove Hölder's inequality. If $f$ or $g$ are zero then it is trivial, so assume $\|f\|_p,\|g\|_q>0$. Define $F=\frac f{\|f\|_p},G=\frac g{\|g\|_q}$. Then $F\in L^p,G\in L^q$ with $\|F\|_p=\|G\|_q=1$. Using Young's inequality, we have
$$\int_X|FG|\ d\mu\le\int_X\left(\frac{|F|^p}p+\frac{|G|^q}q\right)\ d\mu=\frac1p\|F\|_p^p+\frac1q\|G\|_q^q=1.$$
We have shown
$$\frac1{\|f\|_p\|g\|_q}\int_X|fg|\ d\mu=\int_X\left|\frac f{\|f\|_p}\frac g{\|g\|_q}\right|\ d\mu\le1,$$
so we are done. Note that by carefully keeping track of where equality occurs in Young's inequality, one can show that equality occurs if and only if $|f|^p$ and $|g|^q$ are linearly dependent as elements of $L^1$.

Comment: Can you please provide one?

Comment: I have added a proof.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I had a proof: Use Young inequality and then integrate on both sides. But the step of integrating on both sides requires that the integrals be finite. Does it not?

Comment: No, it does not. Indeed, if the right hand integral is infinite then there is no problem (as we are saying LHS$\le\infty$), and if is finite then the comparison principle shows that the left hand integral must also be finite. (Since if $0\le f\le g$ and $g$ is integrable then $f$ is integrable with $\int f\le\int g$.)

Comment: Thank you. It was not so clear to me that it is ok for the integrals to be infinite because in that case it looked to me like the norms were undefined and then the maps were not elements or the $L_p$ spaces in question.

Answer (score 0):

> not clear to me why, if both $\|f\|_p$ and $\|g\|_q$ are finite, this implies that $\|fg\|_1$ is, too.

Note that
$$ 1 < \infty $$
Therefore,
$$ \text{if $b=1$ and $a=\infty$ then $b < a$.} $$
Contraposing,
$$ \text{if $a\le b$ then it is not the case that $b=1$ and $a=\infty$.} $$
Now, Hölder's inequality assures us that if $a=\|fg\|_1$ and $b=\|f\|_p\|g\|_q$ then $a\le b$.  Therefore it is not the case that $\|fg\|_1=\infty$ and $\|f\|_p\|g\|_q = 1$.

Comment: Yes I agree but in the proof of Hölder's inequality one takes the integral on both sides of the Young inequality. It is not clear to me why this step does not require the integrals to be finite.